# How to download the Blob received from the nodejs backend in reactjs to any Operating System in ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, blob

I'm developing a ReactJS web-app where the backend server sends the blob object inside the API response. While downloading the file, the problem is that the file gets downloaded but the contents of the file are just [object Object].
The blob sent by the Backend is something like this :

```
{ 
     success: true,
     message: 'Blob retrived successfully',
     blob:
      Blob {
        [Symbol(type)]: 'text/html',
        [Symbol(buffer)]:
         <Buffer 0a 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 20 6c 61 6e 67 3d 22 65 6e 22 20 78 6d 6c 3a 6c 61 6e 67 3d 22 65 6e 22 20 78 6d 6c ... > },
     name: 'newfile123.html' 
}
```

This is what I have tried in the frontend in ReactJS :

```
const blob = new Blob([response.data.blob]);
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.setAttribute('download', name);
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
```

Name in link.setAttribute is fetched before hitting the API, So no issues with that.

Comment: Where do you get the output in "The blob sent by the Backend is something like this"? From a Node.js console, or within your browser?

Comment: Yes, I get it from the nodejs console

Comment: Right. So you don't know what's being sent over the wire. I do happen to know – that Node.js native Buffer gets turned into a string representation, `"[object Object]"`. As my answer says, you will need to encode it in the backend. You can't solve this in the frontend alone.

Comment: If you look at the response body in your browser's network inspector, I'll _bet_ you'll see the `"[object Object]"` string there, so you know that's what comes from the backend.

Comment: Actually the browser's network inspector shows an empty object for the blob variable. Something like this : ```blob:{}``` All the other variables in the response are fine

Comment: This is the response from the network inspector in the browser  ```{ success: true, message: "Blob retrived successfully", blob: {}, name: "newfile123.html" }```

Comment: Okay, my bet was mildly wrong there then :) – but the point is, the special Blob object gets encoded as a basic empty object. This must be fixed in the backend.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your response and your time in responding to my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send a Blob (or any other binary data for that matter) directly in a JSON API response.

You'll need to encode it somehow on the server (base64 is the most efficient generic encoding for binary data), then decode it on the client.

Comment: Is there no way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sending the blob, the backend code is developed by another person.

Comment: You will need to tell the backend person to fix their code to encode the blob then. You can't send a Node.js blob/buffer over the wire without encoding it.